# Bxslider arrows stop working after few clicks

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I implemented bxslider carousel on a page, and have problem with the arrows controls. everything works great, but after going forward and backwards with the arrows suddenly they stop working after few clicks, this happened especially on mobile (iphone).
Have anyone got such a problem before and how to fix it?